# Xslt code to get minutes past

Tags: xslt, date, time

I get an xml from SQL. The xml has a node that contains date time information.  The xml is getting transformed using xslt. I need to calculate the minutes past in the xslt.

For example, in the xml i have the below node:

2011-08-28T22:11:52.383-07:00

I need to take current time as reference and caculate how many minutes passed by from the date that is there in the xml node. Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution.

Comment: Sorry Dimitre, did not log into to stackoverflow since some days. Looks good, marked as answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   Current time: <xsl:sequence select="current-dateTime()"/>

   Elapsed minutes since: <xsl:sequence select="string(/)"/>:

   <xsl:sequence select=
   "(current-dateTime() - xs:dateTime(/) )
    div
     xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1M')
     "/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>2011-08-28T22:11:52.383-07:00</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
   Current time: 2011-08-29T21:28:27.153-07:00

   Elapsed minutes since: 2011-08-28T22:11:52.383-07:00:

   1396.5795
```

**Explanation**:  The elapsed minutes are calculated as the result of division of two durations:

1. The time difference between now and the specified date-time, and
2. The `xs:dayTimeDuration` value of exactly one minute.